# best practice of deploying code on EC2

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I have a web application built on a MEAN stack.

What are some best practices of deploying my code?  I have come across a few options:

1) Use git.  This effectively does a 'git pull' on EC2, then bounces all the servers.  This seems the easiest, but I did notice all my source code is on EC2.  All I really need on EC2 are the concatenated and minified .js/.css files...I don't need all the source code.  One other issue I've been having with this is during deployment, my CPU usage spikes, mainly due to npm (sometimes taking up to 60-70% CPU usage, and occasionally, hangs).

2) Use Grunt to package up only the stuff I need, then do an SSH or SCP to EC2, and bounce everything.  This ensures I only have what I need on EC2, but feels quite a 'cowboy' approach.

Any perspectives on these 2 options?  Is there a third option I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use option 2, but instead of ssh/scp, you can use GIT.  We use the following steps to deploy to our production servers:

- First use Grunt to package up the stuff
- then commit that production stuff in a separate GIT Repo
- You can create hooks on both your local machine and server machines to automate the deployment
- In local machine, you can create hook to deploy code on all servers whenever you commit the code
- In remote machine, you can create post-receive hook to restart application with latest code whenever any code is pushed